# Rails: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, syntax-error

Ruby on Rails beginner here.

Had this error in localhost:3000

*ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development*

I ran rake db:migrate in terminal and got this:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/EuphoriaComplex/src/bookmarks/db/migrate/20150407050503_add_user_to_bookmark.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

    add has_many :bookmarks to app/models/user.rb
                              ^
/Users/EuphoriaComplex/src/bookmarks/db/migrate/20150407050503_add_user_to_bookmark.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

    add belongs_to :user to app/model/user.rb
                           ^
```

And this is my code in bookmarks/db/migrate in Sublime:

```
class AddUserToBookmark < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :bookmarks, :user_id, :integer

    add has_many :bookmarks to app/models/user.rb

    add belongs_to :user to app/model/user.rb
  end
end
```

I was following this tutorial: http://12devs.co.uk/articles/writing-a-web-application-with-ruby-on-rails/
and I only made it to "Require authentication to manage your bookmarks"

**"Users have many Bookmarks"** is the section in question.

Comment: A comment at the bottom of the tutorial points out that the `add belongs_to :user` should point to `app/model/bookmark.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you exactly where the problem is.

```
add has_many :bookmarks to app/models/user.rb
add belongs_to :user to app/model/user.rb
```

this should not be in a migration since they do not change the schema. You need to add these to the bookmark and user model, so

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
end
```

Comment: looking at the tutorial, i can see why you are confused. Its telling you to add **has_many :bookmarks**
to your file app/models/user.rb

Comment: hi i just posted a new question i would appreciate if you can help me. you answered me last time.

Answer (score 0):

The relationships between models go in the models, the migrations are for the database, it is different... you should keep the `add_column :bookmarks, :user_id, :integer` but the other two lines erase them from your migration, you shouldgo to your `user.rb` model and add `has_many :bookmarks` and go to your `bookmark.rb` model and add `belongs_to :user`

Maybe you can also read this guide, it might help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html